# How to access a particular element that exists in multiple forms with same ID in a particular form when the form name is in variable

Tags: jquery, html

I have Multiple Forms in my page. Each form is having a unique ID. However all the elements in these forms have same ID. I want to access a particular element in a particular form using Jquery. How can i do that

In the Jquery i have following code. I have set the data-radioacceptid attribute in radio element to an incremental value starting from 1.Then i am takin the form id in a variable formno. Now in that form i want to disable a dropdown.But i dont know how to do that. I have tried following

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('custom-qcentryaccept')) {
        var id=$(this).data('radioacceptid');
        var formno="#QCEntryForm" + id;
        $(formno "select[name=QCradiobtnaccept]").prop("disabled",true);
    }
```

Comment: Never use the same id more than once. That's the point of ids.

Comment: Well i am running a foreach loop in php to create multiple forms. Thats why they have same IDs

Comment: Well, you need to change your code logic. Just append a different letter/code to the beginning of each form's ids

Comment: my forms have unique IDs, but the HTML elements in each form has same ID.

Comment: You **cannot** have the same id being used more than once. It will not work. You will need to change how you are outputting ids.

Comment: ok. will try that.. thanks

Comment: In any programming situation, if you attempt to use the same id more than once you will always have problems.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the same id being used more than once. It will not work. You will need to change how you are outputting ids. – Lee Taylor